I have trouble using the alternatives for some commands in older versions of qiskit
I have a code that calculates the transition amplitute between and using the ZZFeatureMap with 4 repetitions and default data mapping function. Use the qasm_simulator with shots = 8192, seed_simulator = 1024 and seed_transpiler = 1024.

x = [-0.1,0.2]
y = [0.4,-0.6]

encode_map = ZZFeatureMap(feature_dimension=2, reps=4)
zz_kernel=QuantumKernel(feature_map=encode_map,quantum_instance=Aer.get_backend('statevector_simulator'))
zz_circuit =zz_kernel.construct_circuit(x,y)
backend =Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator')
job = execute(zz_circuit,backend,shots=8192,
              seed_simulator=1024, seed_transpiler=1024)
counts = job.result().get_counts(zz_circuit)


amplitude= counts_x2['00']/sum(counts_x2.values())


however, Quantum kernel and execute are no longer available in qiskit. So this code isn't work. How can i fix it? I tried several methods but none of them were useful. For instance:

x = [-0.1,0.2]
y = [0.4,-0.6]

# YOUR CODE HERE
zz_map = ZZFeatureMap(feature_dimension=2, reps=4)
zz_kernel = FidelityQuantumKernel(feature_map=zz_map)
zz_circuit = zz_kernel.construct_circuit(x,y)
backend = Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator')
transpiled_circuit = transpile(zz_circuit, backend=backend, seed_transpiler=1024)
job = backend.run(transpiled_circuit, shots=8192, seed_simulator=1024)
counts = job.result().get_counts(zz_circuit)


amplitude = counts['00']/sum(counts.values())


I am open to any suggestions
